# Scala - How to read a csv table into a two dim array/matrix of indefinite size

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, matrix, multidimensional-array

I would like to read from a huge csv file, assign every row to an array via spliting values by ",". In the end I aim to have an array of arrays(rows) which holds the values.
My code is like this so far:

```
val file = "/home/tolga/Desktop/mics18-2/big-data/homework2/covtype.csv/data-10.csv"
for(line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines){
  val seriesArray : Array = line.split(",").map(_.toInt).distinct /*error on this line*/
  println(line)
}
```

Comment: The error message is always interesting. Is it `<console>:15: error: class Array takes type parameters`? How would you interpret it?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: How is this related to apache-spark (which is tagged)? If you intend to read this using Spark (into a DataFrame, Dataset or RDD) - you should use one of Sprak's read operations and not `Source.fromFile`. Otherwise, please remove the apache-spark tag.

Comment: @TzachZohar I actually tried to do it with RDD but failed. I appreciate if you can provide the code for that.

Comment: can you provide some sample data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my testfile, I have to make some adjustments:

```
for(line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines){
     val seriesArray : Array[Int] = line.split (",").filter (_.trim.size > 0).map (_.toInt).distinct
     println(line) }
```

- not Array, but Array[Int] as the error message says
- I have to trim the Strings, maybe an artifact at the line end
- check for size > 0, avoiding "".toInt

The last two might not be relevant for your file.

And no, that doesn't produce 2dim Arrays. It just operates on a single line, assigns it to seriesArray which is a one-dim Array, and overwrites that value for every line.

To preserve all the lines

```
scala> val seriesArray : Array[Array[Int]] = (
     |   for (line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines) yield 
     |     line.split (",").filter (_.trim.size > 0).map (_.toInt).distinct).toArray
```

which reveals, for my testdata:

```
seriesArray: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(), Array(1, 49, 999), Array(), Array(1, 49, 1000), Array(), Array(1, 50, 999), Array(), Array(1, 50, 1000), Array(), Array(1, 51, 999), Array(), Array(1, 51, 1000), Array(), Array(2, 49, 999), Array(), Array(2, 49, 1000), Array(), Array(2, 50, 999), Array(), Array(2, 50, 1000), ...
```

For printing, you need to be a bit patient, since the print statement returns Unit, not data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this make seriesArray a 2 dimensionalArray with all lines included as arrays in it?

Answer (score 0):

For a Spark-based solution, the end result would be an `RDD[Array[Int]]` and not strictly a "two-dimensional array", as an RDD is an abstraction of a partitioned, distributed, immutable "array".

Loading a CSV-file into RDD is simple, but the devil is in the details. Given a simple file such as this `data.csv` file:

```
1,1,3,2
2,22,3,18
3,3,12,25
```

The following would work:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("data.csv").map(_.split(",").map(_.toInt))
```

If, however, the input must be "cleaned" in some way (e.g. remove headers line, trim values, filter out non-integers etc.) you'll have to do so using RDD's methods like `filter` and `map`. If you encounter specific issues with such cleanup, search for the specific issues or post a new question with your code, your data the error you're seeing.